# I am getting an error while i am trying to create an array of image class

Tags: objective-c

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 205003599 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'

I write this code in .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface image : NSObject
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *myimage;
-(image *) randomimage;
@end
```

I implement it on .M file

```
#import "image.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@implementation image
- (instancetype)init
{    
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         _myimage =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Earth.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Jupiter.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Orion.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Saturn.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Venus.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mars.jpg"],
              nil];
    }
    return self;
}
-(image *) randomimage{
    int randimage=arc4random_uniform((int)self.myimage);
    return [self.myimage objectAtIndexedSubscript:randimage];
}
@end
```

Comment: You're getting a random integer for an index which exceeds beyond the bounds of the array of your images. Restrict the random number generator to only generate a number between 0-5 since you only have 6 images in the array.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect? Look at your code:

```
int randimage=arc4random_uniform((int)self.myimage);
return [self.myimage objectAtIndexedSubscript:randimage];
```

`arc4random_uniform` can return anything between 0 and its argument. The argument is `self.myimage` - an *object*. Its value is not an integer, but you are forcing it to be one. What you are getting is thus the memory location of this object, which could be any number at all. So you wind up with a huge number, way outside the actual number of elements in the array. You probably mean `self.myimage.count`, don't you?

Comment: Also don't call `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` when you mean simply `objectAtIndex:`. That's just silly.